# Are you supposed to set up a 'pass by reference' variable beforehand?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

Example from the PHP documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php

```
openssl_public_encrypt ( 
    string $data , string &$crypted , mixed $key [, int $padding =         
    OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING ] 
)
```

In this case it expects $crypted as a passed reference. The function works without setting up $crypted beforehand.

In a lot of example I see $crypted being initialized before calling the function.

```
var $crypted = '';
```

Is this really needed(or technically more correct) or is it fine to not set up the variable even though it is a 'pass by reference' variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More of a comment than an answer - but too long for a comment box. And a fascinating question that leaves me asking "why".

To answer directly:

- NOT declaring the variable will not cause an "NOTICE" in either version - so technically it's not required.
- declaring is therefore a preferential thing. Like [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41740174/1015483) I prefer to declare for readability and clarity. (I also prefer to avoid functions like `extract` that create variables from no-where.) But I'm sure others will disagree.

But this leads to the question of WHY it works like that? And I'd love to know.

---

First thing to note is that variables and variables passed by reference changed a lot from PHP 5 to PHP 7. An interesting read here: https://nikic.github.io/2015/05/05/Internal-value-representation-in-PHP-7-part-1.html that explains the differences.

But in both PHPs, variables are stored in the zval space with a reference counter of how many times the variable is referenced. (That doc above is the best example I've found on explaining it, but there's more in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php))

When you extend PHP and add new functions, you get variables from the Zend API using `zend_parse_parameters`. This means variables passed to the functions are also stored in the zval container and passed between the API and the extension. ([Further reading](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch14_06.htm) - this relates to PHP5 but appears the same for PHP7).

My understanding (and I'm happy to be corrected) is explained in the four code samples:

1)

```
function increment($i) {
    $i++;
}

increment(3);
```

The variable `3` is not declared (obviously), but it needs to be in the zval container for passing to the API. This shows the *the calling function has the capability to generates a variable in zval container*. (As it's not a real variable, I presume it "immmutable" but that's a guess.)

2)

```
function increment($i) {
    $i++;
}

increment($y);
```

This errors as `$y`is not declared first. `Notice: Undefined variable: y in test.php`. So here it's unable to generate `$y` and put in local scope.

3)

```
function increment($i) {
    $i++;
}

$y = 0;
increment($y);
```

The variable is declared and put into zval container. When calling the functions, refcount will be increased so it can be passed to the API. Works as expected.

4)

```
function increment(&$i) {
    $i++;
}

increment(3);
```

This errors `Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in test.php`. This tells us that the variable `3` is rejected by `zend_parse_parameters` as it knows it's immutable, or that the calling function knows the function expects a variable by reference.

5)

```
function increment(&$i) {
    $i++;
}

$y = 0;
increment($y);
```

The variable `$y` is put into zval container in the current scope on the first line, and generates the reference pointer to `$y` (increase refcount twice).

6)

```
function increment(&$i) {
    $i++;
}

increment($y);
```

This is where it goes pear-shapes IMO: Although the variable is not declared, but `$y == 1`. This means that the function must both create the variable and put into zval container in the current scope, and generate the reference pointer to `$y` (increase refcount).

To do this, it must know that the function is expecting a value by reference - otherwise why is the behaviour different from 2?

And none of this answers why it's different. Just because it *can* create a variable (as shown in example 1), why doesn't it in example 2, but it does in example 6?

Answer (score 1):

Although the variable will be created, I prefer to set it explicitly for number of reasons:

- the variable might be used in the function to get data from it
- the variable might not be set in the function, so I don't need to bother with `isset` afterwards
- the variable might already be defined elsewhere in the code, so there is a risk of passing garbage, or receiving garbage, if the function does not change the variable
- there must be few others which I forgot to mention, so let's name it gut feeling

Not sure if any of them apply to `openssl_public_encrypt` in particular, but since you get used to set variables before function calls, changing this behaviour requires more efforts and attention than it deserves.

Comment: In this case I know the function will not use the variable to get data from it. And I know it properly return the value with the variable. It is also enclosed by it's own method scope. So I feel there is justification in just leaving it out for the sake reducing line numbers in this case. I was wondering how others feel about it though. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Yeah, I was tempted to vote to close it as opinion-based =)

Comment: I was unsure about any technical ramifications that I might have been unaware of when leaving out the variable initialization beforehand though. That is why I decided to create the question. Thank for helping out!